# NodeJS: Server-side request data validation

Tags: node.js, validation

What is the right way to validate incoming data on server side?
I'm using lodash for simple validation like `isObject` or `isArray` etc, and [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) for cases when i need to validate, say, if a string `isEmail`. But all this looks awkward and i'm not sure if this gonna hurt performance a lot or not so much.

There should be a way to validate incoming data the more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use [schema-inspector](https://github.com/Atinux/schema-inspector).

It's a module meant to validate json objects based on a json-schema description.

Here is an example from the github README :

```
var inspector = require('schema-inspector');

// Data that we want to sanitize and validate
var data = {
    firstname: 'sterling  ',
    lastname: '  archer',
    jobs: 'Special agent, cocaine Dealer',
    email: 'NEVER!',
};

// Sanitization Schema
var sanitization = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        firstname: { type: 'string', rules: ['trim', 'title'] },
        lastname: { type: 'string', rules: ['trim', 'title'] },
        jobs: {
            type: 'array',
            splitWith: ',',
            items: { type: 'string', rules: ['trim', 'title'] }
        },
        email: { type: 'string', rules: ['trim', 'lower'] }
    }
};
// Let's update the data
inspector.sanitize(sanitization, data);
/*
data is now:
{
    firstname: 'Sterling',
    lastname: 'Archer',
    jobs: ['Special Agent', 'Cocaine Dealer'],
    email: 'never!'
}
*/

// Validation schema
var validation = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        firstname: { type: 'string', minLength: 1 },
        lastname: { type: 'string', minLength: 1 },
        jobs: {
            type: 'array',
            items: { type: 'string', minLength: 1 }
        },
        email: { type: 'string', pattern: 'email' }
    }
};
var result = inspector.validate(validation, data);
if (!result.valid)
    console.log(result.format());
/*
    Property @.email: must match [email], but is equal to "never!"
*/
```

The `sanitization` schema is meant to "clean" your json before validating it (Setting optional values, trying to convert numbers to string, etc).

The `validation` schema describes the properties your json should respect.

You then call `inspector.validate` to check if everything is fine.